# AutoDetectChanges not working when a List navigation property exists

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, navigation-properties

I've encountered a bug, where in some code that relies on EF6, changes aren't being detected (although they are being persisted to the datastore).

When using a `List<Child>` navigation property, changes aren't detected when a property in the parent object is changed.  The EntityState remains Unchanged.

Example Console App (.NET Framework 4.7.2 with NuGet EntityFramework 6.2) code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace EFStateTest
{
    public class Tests
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var context = new StandaloneContext();


            /* First time run, generate some test data to work with */
            if (!context.Set<ParentTable>().Any())
            {
                ParentTable p = new ParentTable()
                {
                    Data = "Foo",
                    Children = new List<ChildTable>()
                    {
                        new ChildTable()
                        {
                            ManyData = "Bar",
                        },
                    },
                };

                context.Set<ParentTable>().Add(p);
            }
            /* nth run, do the test */
            else
            {
                var p = context.Set<ParentTable>().FirstOrDefault();        // Get our test record

                p.Data = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();     // Change some data

                try
                {
                    // Get the state
                    object d = p.GetType().GetField("_entityWrapper").GetValue(p);
                    System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateEntry ose = d.GetType().GetProperty("ObjectStateEntry").GetValue(d) as System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateEntry;
                    Console.WriteLine(ose.State);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not a proxy class");
                }
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
            Console.WriteLine("DONE");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    // Context
    public class StandaloneContext : DbContext
    {
        public StandaloneContext() : base("Server=(local);Database=EFTest;Integrated Security=SSPI")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ParentTableSchema());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ChildTableSchema());

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

    public class ParentTable
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Data { get; set; }

        public virtual List<ChildTable> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildTable
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }
        public virtual string ManyData { get; set; }

        public virtual ParentTable Parent { get; set; }
    }

    public class ParentTableSchema : EntityTypeConfiguration<ParentTable>
    {
        public ParentTableSchema()
        {
            HasKey(m => m.Id)
                .Property(m => m.Id)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            HasMany(m => m.Children)
                .WithRequired(c => c.Parent)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId);
        }
    }

    public class ChildTableSchema : EntityTypeConfiguration<ChildTable>
    {
        public ChildTableSchema()
        {
            HasKey(m => m.Id)
                .Property(m => m.Id)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Run this once to generate the database on the local machine, and again to show the bug.  Changing the property of the parent object (`p.Data = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();`) doesn't change the tracked state of the entity, I'm using reflection to get it here, but it's the same as when using the ChangeTracker in the context.

Now, if you remove the navigation collection for `List<ChildTable> Children`, then the problem goes away (but I'm kinda wanting the navigation property) and the change tracker correctly changes to Modified.

I already have a fix, but it doesn't answer *why*.  Change the navigation property to be defined as `ICollection<ChildTable>` instead of List, IList etc, and it also works.

The documentation I've read on EF so far says that navigation properties need to implement ICollection - which List does.  So what gives here?  Am I getting something else wrong, or missing something completely?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the value of `context.Entry(d).State` before and after you changed the `Data` property of the entity. Also verify that the context configuration does not have `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` disabled.

Comment: Hmm, I won't expect entity state to change by just setting primitive property value of an entity instance (even if it's being proxied). `AutoDetectChanges` should have effect after you access some of the context methods triggering it (listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/auto-detect-changes)). The fact that the changes are persisted in the database proves that they are detected. If you want to be sure, call `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges` explicitly.